# how to get filenames from a folder and keep filenames order unchanged?

Tags: c++, vector, filenames

I have got filenames from a folder and sent names into `vector<string>`, but when I printed the `vector<string>`, I found that the order was not the same order as files in the folder.
My code is shown as follows:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void searchFileInDirectroy( const string& dir, vector<string>& outList );

void searchFileInDirectroy( const string& dir, vector<string>& outList )
{
        WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;
        HANDLE hHandle;
        string filePathName;
        string fullPathName;

        filePathName = dir;
        filePathName += "\\*.*";

        hHandle = FindFirstFile( filePathName.c_str(), &findData );
        if( INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hHandle )
        {
                cout<<"Error"<<endl;
                return ;
        }

        do
        {
                if( strcmp(".", findData.cFileName) == 0 || strcmp("..", findData.cFileName) == 0 )
                {
                        continue;
                }

                fullPathName = dir;
                fullPathName += "\\";
                fullPathName += findData.cFileName;

                if( findData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY )
                {
                        searchFileInDirectroy( fullPathName, outList );
                }
                else
                {
                        outList.push_back(fullPathName);
                }

        } while( FindNextFile( hHandle, &findData ) );

        FindClose( hHandle );
}

int main()
{
    ///get filenames from folder;
    vector<string> pathList;
    searchFileInDirectroy("D:/OpenCV/calculate laef area--cui.ver2.0/source", pathList);

    for(unsigned int i=0;i<pathList.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<pathList[i]<<endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

The result is like that:

[image: result]

What I really want is that the order is from 1 to 12.

Comment: Files in a folder don't have an inherent order.

Comment: You have to sort the vector as FindFile uses the order of the filesystem.

Comment: For (logical) sorting you might need http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb759947(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @MrTux Thank you for your reply. Could you show me a example? I have tried the FindFile method, but did not succeed.

Comment: You can't trust a terminal window "dir" as the order of the actual files in the file table. Such output is altered by things like the DIRCMD environment variable (my preference is `/O:EN`, and it is common for many who like to see folders, then files sorted by extension, then name). If you want a similar order, you need to sort yourself.

Comment: @just_rookie: It's still unclear to me whether you need natural ordering (i.e. you don't like the fact that "12" comes before "2") or the native low-level filesystem order.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yes, I need the natural ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found that the order was not the same order as files in the folder.

You probably mean that they are not ordered naturally, i.e. the numbers in the filenames are seemingly not respected.

This is because **lexigraphical comparison** does not respect maths. **`"12"` is less than `"2"`**, because `"12"` already "wins" for the first character, as the strings are compared character by character and `'1'` is less than `'2'`.

So you first need an algorithm for **natural ordering**. C++ does not provide one, but it provides a way to sort ranges with any given ordering relationship, using [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

```
#include <algorithm>

// ...

struct NaturalOrdering
{
    bool operator()(std::string const &lhs, std::string const &rhs) const
    {
        // ...
    }
};

// ...

vector<string> pathList;

// ...

std::sort(pathList.begin(), pathList.end(), NaturalOrdering());
```

The goal thus becomes to find an algorithm which defines a natural less-than relationship between the two. This not a trivial task if you want to cover each and every corner case. If you search on Google for "string natural order", you will find countless algorithms to use.

Here's a quick self-made one. Its idea is to divide strings into tokens, each containing only digits (like "123") or no digits at all (like "file"). The tokens are then compared individually. If both are numbers, they are converted to ints and compared mathematically, otherwise they are compared lexicographically.

Feel free to take this thing and improve it if it's actually too slow or has other problems. Its intention is more educational than usage in production code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

struct Token
{
    bool is_number;
    std::string string;
};

std::vector<Token> Tokenize(std::string const &input)
{
    std::string const digits = "0123456789";
    std::vector<Token> result;

    if (!input.empty())
    {
        bool inside_number_token = isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(input[0])) != 0;
        std::string::size_type start_current_token = 0;
        std::string::size_type start_next_token = 0;
        do
        {
            if (inside_number_token)
            {
                start_next_token = input.find_first_not_of(digits, start_current_token);
            }
            else
            {
                start_next_token = input.find_first_of(digits, start_current_token);
            }
            std::string const string = input.substr(start_current_token, start_next_token - start_current_token);
            Token token;
            token.is_number = inside_number_token;
            token.string = string;
            result.push_back(token);
            start_current_token = start_next_token;
            inside_number_token = !inside_number_token;
        }
        while (start_current_token != std::string::npos);
    }

    return result;
}

int ToInteger(std::string const &number_as_string)
{
    std::istringstream converter(number_as_string);
    int integer = 0;
    converter >> integer;
    return integer;
}

struct NaturalOrder
{
    bool operator()(std::string const &lhs, std::string const &rhs) const
    {
        std::vector<Token> const tokens_lhs = Tokenize(lhs);
        std::vector<Token> const tokens_rhs = Tokenize(rhs);

        for (std::vector<Token>::size_type index = 0; index < tokens_lhs.size() && index < tokens_rhs.size(); ++index)
        {
            Token const &token_lhs = tokens_lhs[index];
            Token const &token_rhs = tokens_rhs[index];

            if (token_lhs.is_number && token_rhs.is_number)
            {
                int const number_lhs = ToInteger(token_lhs.string);
                int const number_rhs = ToInteger(token_rhs.string);
                if (number_lhs != number_rhs)
                {
                    return number_lhs < number_rhs;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (token_lhs.string != token_rhs.string)
                {
                    return token_lhs.string < token_rhs.string;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> filenames;
    filenames.push_back("file-10.txt");
    filenames.push_back("file-2.txt");
    filenames.push_back("file.txt");
    filenames.push_back("100.txt");
    filenames.push_back("100.txt");
    filenames.push_back("file-23.txt");
    filenames.push_back("file-11.txt");
    filenames.push_back("test-01-a.txt");
    filenames.push_back("test-022-b.txt");
    filenames.push_back("test-03-c.txt");
    filenames.push_back("aaa-10-2");
    filenames.push_back("aaa-10-1");

    std::sort(filenames.begin(), filenames.end(), NaturalOrder());

    for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter = filenames.begin(); iter != filenames.end(); ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << *iter << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
100.txt
100.txt
aaa-10-1
aaa-10-2
file-2.txt
file-10.txt
file-11.txt
file-23.txt
file.txt
test-01-a.txt
test-03-c.txt
test-022-b.txt
```